# Getting error 'table<WishList>' does not contain a defination for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' using mvc c# with edmx linq?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I am going to create a module for the add product to wish list table using MVC C#. For that I have used Entity Framework. I have crated on dbml class in the model folder. I am go for add product in to wish list i am getting error like this :

> "'**table' does not contain a defination for 'Add' and no
>   extension method 'Add' accepting a  first argumnets of type
>   'table' could be found. (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)**"

I have not idea why this error generate here and what is missing here in my code any buddy then please let me know. here below  i have listed my code.

This is my dbml class in to table defintion :

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.WishList")]
public partial class WishList : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Id;

    private string _Laminate_Sheet_Smo;

    private System.Nullable<int> _CustmorId;

    public List<WishList> list { get; set; }

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
partial void OnIdChanged();
partial void OnLaminate_Sheet_SmoChanging(string value);
partial void OnLaminate_Sheet_SmoChanged();
partial void OnCustmorIdChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnCustmorIdChanged();
#endregion

    public WishList()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this.OnIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                this.OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Laminate_Sheet_Smo", DbType="NVarChar(50)")]
    public string Laminate_Sheet_Smo
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Laminate_Sheet_Smo;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Laminate_Sheet_Smo != value))
            {
                this.OnLaminate_Sheet_SmoChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Laminate_Sheet_Smo = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Laminate_Sheet_Smo");
                this.OnLaminate_Sheet_SmoChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_CustmorId", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> CustmorId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CustmorId;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._CustmorId != value))
            {
                this.OnCustmorIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._CustmorId = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("CustmorId");
                this.OnCustmorIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is class i have make custom in my model folder also :

```
 public class WishListCs
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Laminate_Sheet_Smo { get; set; }

    public int CustmorId { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller code :

```
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CookieHelper.GetCookieValue(CookieKeys.WishLaminateId)))
            {

                string pids = CookieHelper.GetCookieValue(CookieKeys.WishLaminateId);
                var v = pids.Split(',');
                var length = v.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    WishList addtbl = new WishList();
                    addtbl.Laminate_Sheet_Smo = v[i];
                    addtbl.CustmorId = Convert.ToInt32(CookieHelper.GetCookieValue(CookieKeys.CustId));
                    db.WishLists.Add() // here  i am getting error 
                    int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(CookieHelper.GetCookieValue(CookieKeys.CustId));
                    var h = db.WishLists.Where(x => x.CustmorId == UserId).Count();
                    CookieHelper.SetCookie(CookieKeys.CountOfCart, h.ToString());
                }
            }
```

This is my code please any one help me how can fix this error.

Comment: @David Browne do you have idea how can fix this error??

Comment: I think it should be `db.WishLists.Add(addtbl)` instead of `db.WishLists.Add()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WishList addtbl = new WishList();
addtbl.Laminate_Sheet_Smo = v[i];
addtbl.CustmorId = Convert.ToInt32(CookieHelper.GetCookieValue(CookieKeys.CustId));
db.WishLists.Add(addtbl); //Add the object into the DBSet
db.SaveChanges(); //Save changes to database.
```